# how to get json data with the following format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've a json file to get a list of test results.
Below is the json file. And a short snippet of the jquery.
I am trying to get the test id from the json and display them as a unordered list.
How can I do that?

```
[
         {
               "Test":{
               "id":"2949",
               "bk_session_id":"qpmz3gd6xw",
               "series_type":"Cars Series",
               "book_type":"A",
               }
         },
         {
               "Test":{
               "id":"2950",
               "bk_session_id":"qpmz3gd6xw",
               "series_type":"Cars Series",
               "book_type":"A",
               }
         }
]


<script type="text/javascript">

     $.getJSON("http://localhost:8888/tests/students.json?id=qpmz3gd6xw", function(data) {
     for (var i in data) 
        {
            alert(data[i].[Test].id);
        }
     }); 

</script>
```

Comment: Maybe it should be like this: alert(data[i].['Test'].id); Because Test without quotes is a variable.

Comment: alert(data[i].['Test'].id); i got an error if i put the quotes

Comment: Sorry, alert(data[i]['Test'].id); without dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the quotes around `Test`, it should be a string and remove the dot before it.

```
alert(data[i]['Test'].id);
```

also your json is not valid, remove the trailing `,` after each book_type.

```
[
         {
               "Test":{
               "id":"2949",
               "bk_session_id":"qpmz3gd6xw",
               "series_type":"Cars Series",
               "book_type":"A"
               }
         },
         {
               "Test":{
               "id":"2950",
               "bk_session_id":"qpmz3gd6xw",
               "series_type":"Cars Series",
               "book_type":"A"
               }
         }
]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ef7Nq/

Comment: alert(data[i].['Test'].id); i got an error if i put the quotes

Comment: @user3343433 Take out the `.` before `[Test]`, `alert(data[i]['Test'].id);`

Answer (score 0):

Try

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/YLAWg/)</kbd>

```
var ul = '';
for (var i in data) 
{
    ul += '<li>'+data[i]['Test'].id+'</li>';
}
$('#el').append($('<ul/>').html(ul));
```

Comment: I think you meant for `var ul = ''`;

Comment: No problem! You do need the `= ''` though, `ul` would return "undefined<li>...</li>" with it the way it is.

Comment: @BillCriswell why `undefined`

Comment: It's because `ul` is `undefined`. It just converts it to a string for the concatenation.

Comment: Right, without the `= ''` it'll give you problems, though.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the items in the array and append nodes for each id.

```
$.each(obj, function (i, item) {
    ul.append($('<li>' + item.Test.id + '</li>'));
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QWtdJ/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do `data[i]['Test'].id` or `data[i].Test.id` since there's no space in the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
alert( data[i].Test.id );
```

**Full Code:**

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8888/tests/students.json?id=qpmz3gd6xw", function(data) {
     for (var i in data) {
            alert( data[i].Test.id );
     }
});
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5dPve/1/)</kbd>